# How do I create hierarchical query with where condition on the children collection

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, .net-5

I have this SQL query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Orders o 
INNER JOIN OrderItems i on o.Id = i.OrderId
WHERE i.SomeFlag = 0
```

How do I turn this SQL into an EF hierarchical query that would return Orders with the OrderItems as child collection?

IMPORTANT: Notice the where condition on OrderItems!

EF Model is as follows:

```
class Order 
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public List<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; set; }
}
class OrderItem {
   public int OrderId { get; set; }
   public int ProductId { get; set; }
   public bool SomeFlag { get; set; }
   public Order Order { get; set; }
}

class MyDbContext : DbContext 
{
    public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    public DbSet<OrderItems> OrderItems { get; set; }
}
```

The query must return `IQueryable<T>` where T cannot not be flat structure. It must be a hierarchy just like Order/OrderItem

Comment: And what does the `OrderItem` class look like?

Comment: Typo: 2 Properties with the same name in DbContext.

Comment: Perhaps a miss understanding but : `db.Orders.Where(..).Include(o => o.OrdersItems)`. Will load the related entities But we are not talking about that here , right ? ref:[EF.Core Loading Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/).

Comment: Use SelectMany : context.Orders.SelectMany(x => x.OrderItmes.Select(y => new {id = x.Id, item = y.OrderItems}).ToList();

Comment: @Self: How would you write the where condition? Notice that I want to filter based on OrderItems. I've noticed that filtered include is now supported, which is almost what I need, except it does outer join and I need inner join or equivalent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Order` & `OrderItem` classes should be look like:

```
class Order 
{
  public int Id { get; set; }

  // Navigation property  
  public IColection<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; set; }
}

class OrderItem
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public int OrderId { get; set; }

  // Navigation property  
  public Order Order { get; set; }
}

class MyDbContext : DbContext 
{
  ...

  public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
  public DbSet<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; set; }
}
```

For Query:

```
_context.Orders.Include(x => x.OrderItems).Where(x => x.OrderItems.Any(q => q.SomeFlag));
```

Now you have all orders with all order items for each one with `true` value for `SomeFlag` property.

In EF5 and above you can use **Filtered Include** such as:

```
_context.Orders.Include(x => x.OrderItems.Where(x => x.SomeFlag));
```

Comment: where is the `WHERE` condition?